# image is not displayed on jsp page

Tags: java, image, hibernate, jsp, servlets

I am saving image path in database using hibernate and storing image in a local folder But when I am not able to display image on another jsp page

This is my servlet code

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String relativePath = getServletContext().getInitParameter("file-upload");
        System.out.println(relativePath);
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

        if (!isMultipart) {
            return;
        }
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        factory.setSizeThreshold(MAX_MEMORY_SIZE);
        factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        // Set overall request size constraint
        upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);


        String savePath = relativePath + File.separator + DATA_DIRECTORY; //specify your path here
        File fileSaveDir=new File(savePath);
        if(!fileSaveDir.exists()){
            fileSaveDir.mkdir();
        }


        try {
            // Parse the request
            List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iter = items.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

                if (!item.isFormField()) {

                    fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    System.out.println( fileName);
                    String filePath = fileSaveDir + File.separator +fileName;
                    File uploadedFile = new File(filePath);
                    System.out.println(filePath);
                    // saves the file to upload directory
                    item.write(uploadedFile);
                    Session sess=null;
                    try
                    {
                        System.out.println("file path is:="+filePath);
                        sess=SessionFactoryCreation.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                        sess.beginTransaction();
                        UploadBean ubBean=new UploadBean();
                        ubBean.setImagepath(filePath);

                        sess.save(ubBean);
                        sess.getTransaction().commit();
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        sess.close();
                    }

                }
            }

      } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
          throw new ServletException(ex);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          throw new ServletException(ex);
      }

  }
```

now I have a jsp page on that I have link it will open another jsp page all the images should be displayed on that...

Comment: does the images stored in your said local folder?you could just return the images file name as a list then in your jsp src="/folder/${imagefilename}" use jstl's foreach

Comment: yes image is stored in my local folder and full path of that image is saved in database... so in jsp i try to display that image path is coming from database but image is not displayed...

Comment: my jsp code fro displaying image<%
Session sess=SessionFactoryCreation.getSessionFactory().openSession();
sess.beginTransaction();
Query q=sess.createQuery("from UploadBean");
List<UploadBean> list=q.list();
for(UploadBean ub:list)
{
 System.out.println("image path+++++++:"+ub.getImagepath());
%>
<img src=""/>
 <img  src="<%=ub.getImagepath()%>">
 
<%}
%>

Comment: if it is an absolute path it will not display to other computers.